# How to change this regex without lookbehind check

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

It should match substring between 0 or more spaces. C++11 does not have look behind. This is possible to rewrite this regex ? Or do I need to install boost and use "full" regex powerful?

The regex: `^\s*(.*(?<! ))\s*$`

The image:

[image]

UPDATE: match in backreference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the inner `*` *lazy* by using `.*?` instead, which makes it match as few characters as possible while still giving you a match. This allows the last `\s*` to consume all the spaces:

```
>>> re.match(r'^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '  asdf asdf ').group(1)
'asdf asdf'
```

Comment: Omg!!! Thats awesome !!! Thank you. I had no idea of that  "lazy" stuff. YOU ARE THE BEST.